# Android: How to programmatically make an Activity Window transluscent?

Tags: android

Is there a way to programmatically make an Activity Window appear transluscent? For my purposes, I cannot use static XML resources.

I attempted to set the background resource to a transluscent color, but that only make the background appear solid black.

Comment: did you find any solution. If yes please share.

Answer (score 15):

write it in your activity class

```
Window window = this.getWindow();
window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. But you can use translucent theme android:Theme.Translucent

Comment: It works but only on base (parent view) of layout, but it's ok for me, good job

Comment: Makes the background to completely BLACK !

Comment: Worked for me after also setting the layout background to transparent `android:background="#00FFFFFF"`

Answer (score 5):

Finally, I find a way to solve this problem.

https://github.com/ikew0ng/SwipeBackLayout/blob/e4ddae6d2b8af9b606493cba36faef8beba94be2/library/src/main/java/me/imid/swipebacklayout/lib/Utils.java

if you want to make a activity translucent

```
Utils.convertActivityToTranslucent(activity);
```

or if you want to make it  opaque

```
Utils.convertActivityFromTranslucent(activity);
```

Comment: in Android 10, maybe need to turn on HARDWARE_ACCELERATED to make this effect work

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but for posterity's sake...you can set the translucent theme programmatically like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Set a Translucent NoTitleBar theme before calling super.onCreate()
    setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

API 30 added a [`setTranslucent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setTranslucent(boolean)) method for achieving this:

```kotlin
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
    setTranslucent(true)
    window.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method `convertActivityFromTranslucent`
https://github.com/ikew0ng/SwipeBackLayout/blob/e4ddae6d2b8af9b606493cba36faef8beba94be2/library/src/main/java/me/imid/swipebacklayout/lib/Utils.java